# I can't call public methods from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

this is class with methods

```
public partial class NewGame : Form
{
  public NewGame()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Icon = new Icon("Resources/iconG.ico");
    comboBoxGenre.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Game.Genre)));
  }

  public string GetGameName()
  {
    return txtbxGameName.Text.Trim();
  }

  public int GetGenreSelector()
  {
    return comboBoxGenre.SelectedIndex;
  }
}
```

this is my main form

```
private void addGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form newGame = new NewGame();
  newGame.ShowDialog(this);
  if (newGame.DialogResult==DialogResult.OK)
  {
    string gameName = newGame.GetGameName(); //this part doesn't work
  }
}
```

i got a error message:

> Error 1
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetGameName' and no extension method 'GetGameName' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

few weeks earlier i wrote similar code and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: You'll live to regret this kind of code, it is impossible to localize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
Form newGame = new NewGame();
```

with

```
NewGame newGame = new NewGame();
```

Your `newGame` variable is of type `Form`, which doesn't contain those methods.
You have defined those methods in `NewGame` class, so they will be *visible* if you use correct type.

If you really need to use parent type (`Form`) they you can cast your object to `NewGame`:

```
Form newGame = new NewGame();
string gameName = ((NewGame)newGame).GetGameName();
```

Answer (score 1):

The static type of the variable `newGame` is `Form`, and so only the methods of `Form` are visible, even though the variable actually points to a `NewGame` object. Make the type of the variable match the actual type of the object, and the methods will be accessible.

```
NewGame newGame = new NewGame();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

replace your method with this one

```
private void addGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  NewGame newGame = new NewGame();
  newGame.ShowDialog(this);
  if (newGame.DialogResult==DialogResult.OK)
  {
    string gameName = newGame.GetGameName(); //this part doesn't work
  }
}
```